# Ajax multiple drop down list

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have 5 drop down lists which is dynamic in nature. But the only problem is all the option values are being fetched from mysql database and i really want the user to know that the query is happening at the backend and he should wait by displaying a gif or a line saying "loading.. " .
I've been looking all over for this and similar questions have been posted by others but i don't seem to get it working . Please help me out. Can somebody please give a easy solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the 5 drop down lists, the question is not solvable without some code and a clearer explanation as to what should happen when you do what.

Comment: Yes. Put up a simple working example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://roshanbh.com.np/dropdown/     Very similar to this ... Except that there are 5 fields . Lets say when a user selects country and if there are some 100 states to choose from . Then i should let the user see a loading symbol until the state dropdown list is ready for display . I could have given the full code but its of 5 files and the code is too big . Thanks.

Comment: @Pavan Are you asking us how to call AJAX to populate the option value for each drop down?

Comment: No i don't have a problem doing that . In the above link , if a user selects country and he waits for the states . But if the states dropdown list is too big i want to show the user a loading icon or a text . How can i achieve this ? I know that similar questions have been already asked and answered but those answers just don't seem to work . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've placed an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cMEaM/embedded/result/

I've kept as much of the existing code the same so you should still recognise it. The `getXMLHTTP` function is the same:

```
function getXMLHTTP() {
    //function to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp = false;

    try {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e1) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}
```

There's a new `sendGet` function to handle the XHR request, which takes success and error callbacks.

```
function sendGet(url, onSuccess, onError) {
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    var method = "GET";

    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    onSuccess(req);
                } else {
                    onError(req);
                }
            }
        }
        req.open(method, url, true);
        req.send(data);
    }
}
```

I borrow a [throbber from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber) to display when the data is loading.

```
var throbberHtml = "<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/29/Throbber-Loadinfo-292929-ffffff.gif'>";
```

And these are the new `getXXX` functions which replace the `<select>` with the throbber while the data is loading:

```
function getState(countryId) {
    var div = document.getElementById('statediv');
    var oldInnerHTML = div.innerHTML;

    var onSuccess = function(req) {
        div.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    };
    var onError = function(req) {
        div.innerHTML = oldInnerHTML;
        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
    };

    div.innerHTML = throbberHtml;
    sendGet("findState.php?country=" + countryId, onSuccess, onError);
}

function getCity(countryId, stateId) {
    var div = document.getElementById('citydiv');
    var oldInnerHTML = div.innerHTML;

    var onSuccess = function(req) {
        div.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    };
    var onError = function(req) {
        div.innerHTML = oldInnerHTML;
        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
    };

    div.innerHTML = throbberHtml;
    sendGet("findCity.php?country=" + countryId + "&state=" + stateId,
            onSuccess, onError);
}
```

There are other improvements that could be made, but I tried to keep in the sprit of your existing code as much as possible.

E.g. you can see that most of code in the `getXXX` functions is the same, so you could refactor these to use mostly the same code. Also, using a JS framework such as jQuery will replace the XHR code with better, more cross-browser compatible code. It's usually always better to avoid reinventing the wheel when it comes to code!

And you may possibly decide that sending the HTML for a `<select>` tag is not the best data format for the XHR. You might go with [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) which would decouple your presentation from the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul Grime .. It is partially working . How will i make the <select> appear when the data is ready to be displayed i.e., how will i make the throbber disappear ? Your help is greatly appreciated . Thanks!

Comment: Yes it does . What i'm asking is do i need to make any changes in the findState and findCity files?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to make changes if you want to keep your XHR response format as HTML. If you used some other data format, then you would have to recreate a `<select>` object using Javascript on the client and then populate this `<select>` with `<option>` elements built using the received data. You would also need to set the `onchange` on the new `<select>`. But leaving it as per the example may be fine for your needs. If the answer helped then please accept so it's not left unanswered.